# Max function in python for country data

Tags: python

Hi I have an example dataset of the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FdEH.png)

I am trying to use the max function to find the top 3 countries with the highest number of hotels.

I used the following code in python:
print(data['Number of hotels'].max)

However, it doesn't give the exact name of the country when printing this code. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Where is your minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing your list of hotels and numbers from a CSV then you are likely dealing with a list of lists.  Something like this would work:

```
number_of_hotels = [
    ['Canada', 6555], 
    ['USA', 66666], 
    ['UK', 77777],
    ['Australia', 1000000]
]

print(max(number_of_hotels, key=lambda x: x[1]))
['Australia', 1000000]
```

No need for extra library imports.

Comment: Would the following work:                                                                
max = ad.groupby('coutry')['numver of hotels'].max()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` from `collections`

```
from collections import Counter

country_hotels = {
    'Canada': 6555, 
    'USA': 66666, 
    'UK': 77777,
    'Australia': 1000000
}

print(Counter(country_hotels).most_common(1)[0]) #('Australia', 1000000)
```

Comment: Would the following work:                                                                
max = ad.groupby('coutry')['numver of hotels'].max()

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be dealing with a `pd.DataFrame`, you can achieve this with [`df.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html). (Check the `keep` parameter on how to handle potential duplicates.)

**Setup**

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Countries': [*'ABCDE'],
        'Number of hotels': np.random.randint(0,100,5)})

print(data)

  Countries  Number of hotels
0         A                22
1         B                99
2         C                83
3         D                 7
4         E                72
```

**Code**

```
data.nlargest(n=3, columns='Number of hotels')

  Countries  Number of hotels
1         B                99
2         C                83
4         E                72
```

Also possible with [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). I.e.:

```
data.sort_values(by=['Number of hotels'], ascending=False).iloc[:3]
```

Comment: Would the following work:                                                                
max = ad.groupby('coutry')['numver of hotels'].max()                           Because some countries have 2 or more information due to the date of data being collected

Comment: You can do `data.groupby('Countries', as_index=False).sum().max()`. But `max` will only get you *one* country with the highest number of hotels. You were looking for the top 3. So, do: `data.groupby('Countries', as_index=False).sum().nlargest(n=3, columns='Number of hotels')`.

Comment: @LilyTee: you're welcome.  If the answer offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question.

Comment: From here if I wanted to work out the total number of countries, and total number of hotels. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: These are basic calculations on a `pd.DataFrame` or `pd.Series` (one column inside a df being a series). Try `df['Countries'].nunique()` and `df['Number of hotels'].sum()`. In general, have a thorough look at the documentation: [`frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) and [`series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html). You'll find all the operations you can perform here, with easy examples. If doing so still leaves you with questions on how to approach an issue, try googling and searching SO. If all fails, put up a new Q here on SO. Good luck!